# I just finished a project, and i added to my JMenu an image, how to keep it in the jar file

Tags: java, image

I just finished a project, and i added to my JMenu an image, i exported it as runnable jar file and when i run it on a different computer, the images aren't appearing. ( because they are on my computer ).
Is it possible to add these images to the actual runnable jar? How? this is what i use to get my image.

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jeff\\Desktop\\16 (1).jpg"));
```

Comment: why not you place the image along your .java files and get it through getClass().getResource(your fileName.extension) ?

Comment: How do i do that... it doesn't work for me ...

jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("161.jpg") );

i did this.

Comment: see the image name, it is 16 (1).jpg or 161.jpg??

Comment: it is 161.  i get this: http://pastebin.com/zJejhDF0

Comment: have you placed the image along the .java file ?? and also try "/161.jpg"

Comment: i placed my image in the src/ folder. where the two classes are.
i also tried /161 and still not working

Comment: public class IconImageTest{
    public IconImageTest() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("ImageIcon Test");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png")))); 
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new IconImageTest();
    }
    
}

Comment: I have done the above way it is working for me in NetBeans :)

Comment: i did the following... i copied the 2 files in every possible directory in my java project, and it seems to be working... but now when i export it, and run it, nothing happens, tough in the compiler its opening.

Comment: "/161.jpg" try this way, dont run the code but just create the jar

Comment: tried, still not working. the program compiles fine, but when i export the executable jar file , it is not opening on double click

Comment: which IDE you are using??, I think the problem is that you are creating the jar in a wrong way

Comment: Eclipse,   export-> executable jar file -> package libraries into generated jar -> finsih

Comment: Export
Java, Runnable JAR File
Launch configuration -- here select your main class.

Comment: Thats what i am doing... i did select my main class. if it pleases you my skype is jeff_pascal (Romania) if you prefer to chat.

Comment: try NetBeans I love that and it does not give any problems

Comment: how do i build it in netbeans? to package the libraries into generated jar

Comment: the same way put your images along your .java file and then right click on your project > set Configuration > customize then select run from the hierarchy and then select your main class when you done that again right click on your project and clean and build, you can get your jar from your dst folder located in Netbeans Projects

Comment: i get the error a java exception has occured when using netbeans... thats the problem... on my computer it works fine but on others it doesn't

Comment: update your jdk and netbeans too :)

Comment: i did... and it does the same thing...

Comment: uninstall and reinstall all the jdk and IDE's LOL

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your images as resources into your jar. You can achieve that by putting your images into source directory (basiclly into your classpath). Later on you will be able to access them as resources inside your application.

Comment: I did that(getClass().getResource(your fileName.extension)), i basically copied the file in every possible directory, and it is now working, but now when i export the jar file and double click it, it won't open, even though it opens in the IDE

Comment: in such case you images should bee in root directory in jar (without subdirs). It is hard to tell why your .jar is not opening. What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it, 1st of all, to get rid of the Exception error, i had to downgrade my jdk from 8 to 7.
Second, and last, to get a file added to the jar, i just had to import it from the project with getResource.